# Printing multiple files through javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I need to print multiple files using javascript. Print single file works fine but as soon as I try and print multiple files, I get only one printed.

My javacript is as under

```
function LoadPrint() {
    if (document.getElementById("pdf").src !== "") {
        var frm = document.getElementById("pdf").contentWindow;

        frm.focus();
        frm.print();
    }

    return false;
}
```

and I call it from c# as below

```
foreach (var str in filenames)
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Print", "LoadPdfFile('" + "/Templates/" + str + "');", true);
```

How can I tell RegisterStartupScript to wait until the file is printed?

Comment: You should build a function that would load the next after print, but I have a feeling that is going to be a mess.

Comment: RegisterStartupScript runs on the server. Not on the client. You'll need to add logic to your client side code for sequentially printing the files.

Comment: Just some idea which is a bit off-topic: In our application, we create a joined PDF which contains all selected PDFs to print in one file, big gain if you have a greater number of files to print which would basically go all to the same printer anyway etc. you can do this with `iTextSharp`, `PDFSharp` and others APIs which exist for C# and can be used freely.

Comment: Thanks. I have to think of something else now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a component to generate a pdf, you'll have the functionality to create one pdf by merging many.

I suggest you write a method to create a new pdf with a pagebreak between each one and let the server handle it instead of the client